# Problema ao conectar MySQL no Python 3.4

Tags: mysql, python, django, python-3.x

Acabo de instalar meu ambiente virtual, instalei o PyMysql e criei um projeto, porém, ao tentar iniciar um APP `python manage.py startapp nome`, surgiu o seguinte problema:

```
Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

Como posso configurar o MySQL e resolver isso?

Meu `settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'meudb',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '123',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para o django se comunicar com o MySQL, você precisa instalar uma biblioteca adicional no ambiente em que você estiver usando. Além disso, essa biblioteca deve ser compatível com a engine do Django, o que não é o caso do PyMySQL.

De acordo com a [documentação oficial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers), você tem 3 opções: [MySQLdb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.4), [mysqlclient](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient) e o [MySQL Connector/Python](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python). Somente as duas últimas opções são compatíveis com o Python 3.

Ainda de acordo com a documentação, a biblioteca recomendada a ser instalada é a **mysqlclient**. Para instalá-la, utiliza o pip:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Lembre-se de fazer isso após a ativação do ambiente virtual.

Comment: O erro persiste.

Comment: Acabei de criar um ambiente de testes com Python 3.4.3, Django e mysqlclient e tudo funcionou perfeitamente. Removi o módulo mysqlclient e obtive o mesmo erro que você. Logo, você tem certeza que consegiu instalar o mysqlclient?

Comment: Também fiz o teste: mudei a versão do Python para 3.4, criei um novo ambiente virtual, instalei o Django1.8, depois o mysqlclient. Criei um novo projeto (django-admin startproject nome) e finalmente fiz a alteração no arquivo settings.py. Ao tentar criar um novo App deu novamente a mensagem de erro.

Comment: Qual seu sistema operacional? As bibliotecas de desenvolvimento do MySQL estão instaladas? Se você abrir o interpretador do seu ambiente virtual e digitar import MySQLdb, o que acontece?

Comment: >>> import mysqldb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'mysqldb'

Comment: so: linux mint 17

Comment: importante que você digite respeitando as letras maiúsculas e minúsculas.

Comment: ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

Comment: Se eu mudar a versão do python para python2.7, o mysql funciona normalmente. Somente na versão 3.4 é que apresenta o problema. Já instalei o python-MySQLdb

Comment: Você ativou o ambiente virtual antes de instalar?

Answer (score 0):

Você deve instalar o mysql-python: `pip install mysql-python`